# Receiving an HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST from SAML2 Response

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have a Windows Server 2019 running an IIS web server. My organization uses ADFS 2016 and a team has configured the IdP integration in ADFS on my behalf. Everything (accounts, server, etc) are part of an AD domain network (all within same domain infrastructure).

I am building a .NET 6 app and deploying to the server using this example which uses itfoxtec-identity-saml2: [How to Authenticate with SAML in ASP.NET Core and C#](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp)

The app launches fine. When I click the login button I'm presented with an error upon redirect back to the app: "HTTP ERROR 400".

**Browser console:**
x Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. (anonymous) @ VM9:2762

**Header data from the developer console:**
Request URL: https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*/ADFSTest
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: 10.137.0.7:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
date: Tue, 29 Mar 2022 21:02:57 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
:authority: oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*
:method: POST
:path: /ADFSTest
:scheme: https
accept
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 3813
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
origin: https://dev.adfs.federation.*deleted*
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://dev.adfs.federation.*deleted*/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Microsoft Edge";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-site
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/98.0.4758.119 Safari/537.36 Edg/98.0.1108.76

**SAML Response (decoded)**

```html
<samlp:Response ID="_df09235a-cd8e-40bf-a5b4-03aa6c1bf55e" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2022-03-29T21:02:57.580Z" Destination="https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*/ADFSTest" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_ca71b9ef-4bf8-45b3-930c-a7bbe58a0dc0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://dev.adfs.federation.*deleted*/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_df09235a-cd8e-40bf-a5b4-03aa6c1bf55e"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>3Z+f+F61txOvBDBdtd2TXlt51Gs8mxXgtBJQu4zVXfE=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>X2hy*deleted*</ds:SignatureValue><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIC8*deleted*</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></KeyInfo></ds:Signature><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" /></samlp:Status></samlp:Response>
```

**RelayState:** https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted/ADFSTest/=%2F

**Additional Info:**
The ADFS IdP reads metadata from a URL that I have provided them. The metadata looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                     validUntil="2032-03-12T19:19:05Z"
                     cacheDuration="PT604800S"
                     entityID="https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*/ADFSTest" index="0" />
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

**The appsettings.json is as follows:**

```html
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Saml2": {
    "IdPMetadata": "https://dev.adfs.federation.*deleted*/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
    "Issuer": "https://oitctxwbdcsp1.*deleted*",
    "SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
    "CertificateValidationMode": "ChainTrust",
    "RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I am new to SAML2 and authentication in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error in the SAML Response from AD FS. The error status is `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder`.

There is an error on AD FS stopping the login sequence.

Comment: Your pointing this out solved my issue. I worked with our ADFS team and discovered that I had signing issues. I needed to import my SP's .pfx file containing the public/private certificate for proper signing. I initially thought I needed the IdP's SignatureValidationCertificateFile also but it seems that it was already pulled from the IdPMetadata xml URL. Thanks for your quick response.